# jQuery ajax GET XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, get, postman

I am trying to make a call to a Rest API using jQuery ajax.

In Postman this making a GET request with this URL works fine, but in the application I am getting the following error:

> **XMLHttpRequest cannot load** https://application.appspot.com/apiMethod?email=email@gmail.com&area=Business. **Invalid HTTP status code 404**

here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#saveChanges").click(function()    {
            $.ajax({
                   method: 'GET',
                   url: '<?php  echo getenv ( 'RESTAPIURL' )  ?>apiMethod',
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   data: {
                      email:  '<?php  echo getenv ( 'DEVMAIL' )  ?>',
                      area: 'Business'
                   },
                   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                       console.log(error);
                       console.log(xhr);
                       console.log(status);
                     },


                   dataType: 'json',
                   headers: "Authorization: <?php  echo getenv ( 'TEST_APIKEY' )  ?>",
                   success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                       alert(data);
                     },
                });

            });
</script>
```

If anyone knows why this error happens, some information would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you PHP is worknig properly?

Comment: Yes, the PHP echos above make the request URL correctly. When I copy and paste the URL into Postman it calls the Rest API successfully.